# Android Sync DB Data to Server in a Separate Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, android-syncadapter, android-workmanager

I have use-case in my app where in for every minute lot of data gets stored in local database from a Producer thread in my app. Now i need a Sync Thread which independently checks local database for data every minute and uploads data if there are any. This Sync Thread should be stopped when there is no more data to upload. And should be able start whenever producer again puts data on to db.

I went through HandlerThread, Work Manager and Sync Adapter. Should i be using one of these or are there any better approaches for my use-case. Please shed some knowledge on this. Let me know if more info is needed.

This is how I use executor and have my Producer Thread.

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ProducerThread(queue), 60,
                60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: i suggest you use work manager

Comment: But i need this data to be upload periodically (for every minute). But in PeriodicWorkRequest builder min time is 15 min. How do i overcome this barrier?

Comment: why exactly is your time every minute? isn't that a bit too much? If there is not specific reason why it has to be so frequent, i suggest you actually slow down the uploads. If you can't you may want to look at (JobScheduler) or [Alarms (min alarm distance is 1 min) with BroadcastReceivers and IntentService]

Comment: It's for the purpose of showing live user data in indoor map. So we need it to be a minute.

Comment: Try taking a look at Firebase too then i would suggest, that should also help you along with my previous comment. Plus since firebase is already Async, you wouldnt need the IntentService

Comment: Yeah but unfortunately not in a position to use Firebase. How about AlarmManger for my usecase?

Comment: Yea alarm-manager will help you. Do factor in Doze mode though. Your use case will not work in doze mode even with setexactandallowwhileidle as that only supports alarms at a gap of 9 -10 mins. Other than that yea will work for you

Comment: Yeah cool. For doze mode we have our app whitelisted. Thanks :)

Comment: @SRBhagwat : what did you use then?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Foreground Service` for your app. For `PeriodicWorkRequest`s the min interval duration is `15 min` and there is no way around that. Also you get a `10 min` execution window, which it looks like might not be enough because this is an on-going sync operation.

Comment: How about scheduling  OneTimeWorkRequest each minute from a separate Thread ? I need this Data to be sent to server every minute.